# PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'writer.gdal'

Tags: conda, gdal, lidar, pdal

I'm trying to create a raster .tif from a ground classified point cloud file using PDAL (https://pdal.io/en/latest/).

I installed PDAL following the Quickstart instructions provided in the PDAL documentation (https://pdal.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). I successfully created a classified point cloud file. I want to create a raster digital elevation model (DEM) using writer.gdal. I have GDAL installed on conda using the following command: conda install -c conda-forge gdal

I wrote a pipeline using Visual Source Code following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvL25Y7O-Dw).

```
{
    "pipeline":[
        "ground_north.laz",
        {
            "type":"writer.gdal",
            "filename":"north_dem.tif",
            "gdaldriver":"GTiff", 
            "output_type":"all",
            "resolution":"1.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I call the pipeline using this command 'pdal pipeline to_raster.json' I get the following error message:

`PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'writer.gdal'.`

`You probably have a version of PDAL that didn't come with a plugin`

`you're trying to load.  Please see the FAQ at https://pdal.io/faq`

How can I fix this?

I'm very new to using conda, and I apologize if this isn't clear. I'd appreciate any and all help/tips/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in your type, it should read `writers.gdal` not `writer.gdal`.

A sample pipeline is below.

```
{
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "filename": "ground_north.laz",
      "type": "readers.las",
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.gdal",
      "filename":"north_dem.tif",
      "gdaldriver":"GTiff", 
      "output_type":"all",
      "resolution":"1.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you're trying to isolate specific classes for your raster you'll also need a filter in your pipeline something like:

```
    {
      "type": "filters.range",
      "limits": "Classification[2:2]"
    },
```